# Matrix equation: $A−A(A + B)^{−1}A = B−B(A + B)^{−1}B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$A−A(A + B)^{−1}A = B−B(A + B)^{−1}B$

A+B is nonsingular

So i got this equation i have to show that both sides are equal but only A + B is nonsingular A and B are not. I got to how solve it when A and B are also nonsingular but i realised that there aren't. So now i dont get how to solve it. Can someone give me a hint on how to do it?

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Solve for what ? What is the context ? What did you try ?

Comment: Nicolas FRANCOIS, as i said i have to show both sides of the equation are equal. A and B are both nxn matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A+B$ is non-singular we have that 
$$(A+B)^{-1}(A+B)=I\implies A(A+B)^{-1}A+A(A+B)^{-1}B=A.$$
and similarily 
$$(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}=I\implies A(A+B)^{-1}B+B(A+B)^{-1}B=B.$$
Thus on subtracting the two we get:
$$A(A+B)^{-1}A-B(A+B)^{-1}B=A-B.$$
Rearrange this to get your answer.